# How to reduce the size of the glyphicon in boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

I am using a glyphicon icon and it is used inside a button. But the size of the icon is too big for the button. How can I reduce the size of the glyphicon ?
I already used small tag and it didin't work.

Comment: `.glyphicon { font-size: 12px }` or lower. You could also give the glyphicon a ID to only effect this one.

Comment: Show us your code. We need an [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline style format to adjust font size for specific glyphicon elements

```
 <button>
       <span style="font-size:12px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
   </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the glyphicon you can try like below:

```
    .glyphicon {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

For a specific icon:

```
    .glyphicon.glyphicon-plus {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your normal implementation of the glyphicon:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

You could just give all glyphicons a new size with:

```
.glyphicon { 
    font-size: 12px 
}
```

or you could give the span a `ID`:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true" id="small_glyphicon"></span>
```

and change the size for the `ID`:

```
#small_glyphicon {
    font-size: 12px; /* or lower */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glyphicons are essentially fonts. So, you could specify the desired size through the `font-size` property.

I tend to keep these four classes `glyphicon-lg`, `-md`, `-sm` and `-xs` in my projects, as they generally work well with `btn-lg`, `-md`, `-sm` and `-xs`.

```css
.glyphicon-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.glyphicon-md {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.glyphicon-sm {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.glyphicon-xs {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-lg glyphicon-asterisk"></div>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-md glyphicon-asterisk"></div>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-sm glyphicon-asterisk"></div>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-xs glyphicon-asterisk"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as changing the font-size (or style for that matter).
Use style= "font-size: 12px;"

You can use in-line style format e.g.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true" style= 
  "font-size: 12px;"></span>
</button>
```

or in your custom CSS file e.g.

```
.glyphicon{
   font-size: 12px;
      }
```